# MySQL slow down suddenly

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

On the same database MySQL 5.7.17 (InnoDB) on local PC I run query which takes 25s but after log in on the same db once again I achieved longer execution time - 50s. I suspect that it's MySQL performance issue. It appears many times, sometimes db is performing query longer, next time db speed up and execution takes less time. I'm testing it on many queries in the cmd line client.
One thing which I have changed in cfg is `innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G` in my.ini
Have anybody has any suspicion what may cause this decrease of performance, or what I have to check?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: it would help to see the query...

Comment: I think it's not the matter of query implementation, but rather mysql server performance issue, because as I said "sometimes db is performing query longer, next time db speed up and execution takes less time"

Comment: Do you have at least 8GB of RAM?

Comment: 25-50s is a long time; let's see if we can improve the indexes/schema/query/etc.  Maybe in doing so, the 25:50 issue will go away.

Comment: Yes, I have 8GB RAM